# Create shortcut from VBScript almost works fine

Tags: c#, vbscript

I created a VBScript that creates a shortcut. The shortcut works fine, but if I move the shortcut to some other location the app crashes, i.e the shortcut fails.

If I create the shortcut manually I can put it anywhere, so I guess my code is missing something

Here is the `.VBS` script:

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
relativePath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(relativePath&"\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.lnk")
    oLink.TargetPath = relativePath&"\MyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe"        
oLink.Save
```

Same thing happens if I create the shortcut from C# code:

```
WshShell shell = new WshShell();           
string shortcutAddress = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\AppsSolutionsMyApp\bin\Debug\shortcut.lnk";
 IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
 shortcut.Description = "New shortcut for my app";
 shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+N";
 shortcut.TargetPath = @"C:\Users\me\Desktop\AppsSolutionsMyApp\bin\Debug\MyApp.exe";
 shortcut.Save();
```

Comment: Have you tried to define the `oLink.WorkingDirectory` property?

Comment: @MCND After setting the `oLink.WorkingDirectory=relativePath&"\MyApp\bin\Debug"` it worked. plz post as answer aand earen some rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Dim baseFolder, linkFile, targetPath

    With WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        baseFolder = .BuildPath( .GetParentFolderName( WScript.ScriptFullName ), "MyApp\Bin\Debug" )
        linkFile   = .BuildPath( baseFolder, "MyApp.lnk" )
        targetPath = .BuildPath( baseFolder, "MyApp.exe" )
    End With 

    With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CreateShortcut( linkFile )
        .TargetPath = targetPath
        .WorkingDirectory = baseFolder
        .Save
    End With
```

One thing that can affect the behaviour of the process start is what the default directory for the new process will be. This is handled inside the link file by the `WorkingDirectory` property.

Also, while not needed this time, it is cleaner to use the `FileSystemObject`'s `BuildPath` method to concatenate paths to avoid possible problems (as said, not in this case, but ...) with double backslashes when directly concatenating strings.